# How to get the index of an item in a listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

If I have a `listbox Item`, how do I get its `index` in a list? I have a `databound` application which lists out data that a user has previously saved. However, I want to be able to delete particular data in the list using a `contextMenu`.

So how do I get the list index of an item that was held to bring up the context menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not access the [SelectedIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex(v=VS.95).aspx) (MSDN) of the control?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I want to be able to delete particular data in the list using a ContextMenu.

You can bind the item directly to the `ContextMenu` as a `CommandParameter`, for your delete command. This is a much better approach to the problem.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Attach the ContextMenu to the top container in your ItemTemplate. -->
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <!-- Here we bind the current item to the RemoveCommand -->
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                          Header="remove item" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <!-- The actual DataTemplate -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I see. However, I need that item also deleted from the user's internal storage and to get the exact item, I need its index number in the array. Even if I remove the item on screen this way i dont' think it'll affect the local storage

Comment: If you databound the items, you will get the exact item, as the CommandParameter. Then you can remove it from both the isolated storage, and the ObservableCollection displaying the items to the view. The index number won't help you.

Comment: Ah thanks. Which function do I use to remove it? I'm using 

ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = this.MainListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;

To select the item, but how to remove it from the ObservableCollection?

Comment: You really don't understand command bindings, do you? You'll need to go read up on how Commands works for Silverlight, and MVVM in general. What you're doing now is completely wrong.